# Primefaces Tag Cloud throwing a null pointer exception

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to add the tag cloud component to my jsf page but it's throwing a null pointer exception.
Before adding this component , the page render normally.I used the exact code of the showcase and i added the managedBean to my faces-config.
I am using eclipse kepler, glassfish 4 and primefaces 4
Here is a snippet of my code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:head>
    <meta></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
     </h:head>
<h:body>
     <p:tagCloud model="#{tagCloudBean.model}">  
    <p:ajax event="select" update="msg" listener="#{tagCloudBean.onSelect}" />  
</p:tagCloud> 
                        <p:inputText size="56"></p:inputText>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:10px">
                            <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit"
                                icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                            <p:commandButton id="clearButton" type="button" value="Clear"
                                onclick="PF('editor').clear()" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
```

And this the log

```
      2013-11-22T16:11:03.284+0100|Grave: Error Rendering View[/forum.xhtml]
       java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.primefaces.component.tagcloud.TagCloudRenderer.encodeMarkup(TagCloudRenderer.java:59)
   at org.primefaces.component.tagcloud.TagCloudRenderer.encodeEnd(TagCloudRenderer.java:38)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
   at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
   at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:304)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:262)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:133)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:72)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

    2013-11-22T16:11:03.291+0100|Avertissement: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]:     Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.tagcloud.TagCloudRenderer.encodeMarkup(TagCloudRenderer.java:59)
at org.primefaces.component.tagcloud.TagCloudRenderer.encodeEnd(TagCloudRenderer.java:38)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:304)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:262)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:133)
at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:72)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the first line?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.tagcloud.TagCloudRenderer.encodeMarkup(TagCloudRenderer.java:59)
```

Ah okay, let's look at line 59 of the [source code of `TagCloudRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0-20130705.184420-2/org/primefaces/component/tagcloud/TagCloudRenderer.java#TagCloudRenderer.encodeMarkup%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,org.primefaces.component.tagcloud.TagCloud%29):

```
59        for(TagCloudItem item : model.getTags()) {
```

Well, looks like either `model` as defined by `<p:tagCloud model="#{tagCloudBean.model}">` is `null` or its `getTags()` method returned `null`.

Logically, this can in turn have the following causes:

1. `#{tagCloudBean}` doesn't exist and is thus `null`.
2. `#{tagCloudBean.model}` returned `null`.
3. `#{tagCloudBean.model.tags}` returned `null`.

As you indicated to have copypasted the [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tagCloud.jsf), which contains the right model, but lacks the bean management annotations, I gather that it's caused by #1.

Adding it to `faces-config.xml` is unnecessary and you most likely did it wrong, e.g. using a managed bean name of `TagCloudBean` instead of `tagCloudBean`. Making it a managed bean the usual JSF 2.x way as follows should fix the issue of `#{tagCloudBean}` being `null`. It namely defaults to the right managed bean name already.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TagCloudBean {}
```

Comment: Actually I annotated the managedBean after pasting the code but I was returning a NullPointerException because it was called from the jsf page using  `#{tagCloudBean.model}` and when i changed it to `#{TagCloudBean.model}` as it was written in the managedBean it worked.

Comment: Apparently you mistakenly explicitly specified a managed bean name of `TagCloudBean` by `@ManagedBean(name="TagCloudBean")` instead of leaving the framework to use the default name. You should not do that, just use the annotation without any attribute, exactly as in my answer. The same applies to the `<managed-bean-name>` in `faces-config.xml`. Instance variable names must start with lowercase. You also don't do `TagCloudBean TagCloudBean = new TagCloudBean();` in regular Java code, but instead you do `TagCloudBean tagCloudBean = new TagCloudBean();` right?

Comment: i didn't change the name in the managedBean but i wrote `TagCloudBean `in the `faces-config.xml` . You're right that's why it didn't work

Comment: Just wanted to add another thing to check for anyone else stumbling upon this issue: Make sure you are using the correct import for @ManagedBean! The wrong one is javax.annotation.ManagedBean. The right one is javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean.